# google-chrome open url in current tab through ssh/remotely

Tags: linux, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Basically I need to issue an ssh command to open a url in the current tab
if i try to run chrome with say

```
google-chrome http://yahoo.com
```

it adds a new tab to the already existing window.

I looked through the command line switches but did not see anything useful...

Anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here are [all the command line switches](http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc) for `google-chrome`. Searched with all possible keywords. But it seems there is none for refreshing the active lab.

Comment: I actually already looked through all of those (searched and actually read through each one) and didn't find anything useful.
I modified my question, I need to open a new url in the current tab not refresh it.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there isn't any standard way or command-line switch to do that, but as a workaround, if you can install a custom add-on on destination machine then you would create a **Chrome Add-on** which reads passed arguments (in form of a url), parse that url and then executes your custom command.

These custom commands could be anything achievable through a Chrome Add-on: in this case refreshing current tab's content.