# Open URL in Chrome's current tab from command line

Tags: google-chrome

I'd like to make a call from the command line/Windows run dialogue to open a given URL in the current tab of a running Chrome.

I don't find a flag to acheive this: http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags

Any ideas?

*(the feature is needed to allow a CTI client to pop websites to the user without tab-flooding the user's browser. This obvisouly require the CTI client to take responsibility for not redirecting the user away from a relevant website)*

(This question is a cleaner version of this question: [google-chrome open url in current tab through ssh/remotely](https://superuser.com/questions/387590/google-chrome-open-url-in-current-tab-through-ssh-remotely))

Answer (score 2):

It was not supported in the year you asked it and is still not supported now:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=141942

Total shame.